# Can a multi-attack pounce be done twice?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack, multiattack

A deinonychus has 40 feet movement speed so can it:
move 20 ft> multiattack> 1st claw> pounce> bonus action bite> move 20 ft to another creature> 2nd claw>pounce>multiattack bite???

Comment: Related: [Can a creature finish its multi-attack after it pounces?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98160)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 13):

## It can knock over two creatures, but only has a single bonus action to Bite with.

Since the Bite attack from Pounce is a bonus action, the Deinonychus can only make one per turn.

> Pounce. If the deinonychus moves at least 20 feet straight toward a creature and then hits it with a claw attack on the same turn, that target must succeed on a DC 12 Strength saving throw or be knocked prone. If the target is prone, the deinonychus can make one bite attack against it **as a bonus action.**

So it can move 20ft and start its multiattack. It Bites the target (part of Multiattack), and then hits the first Claw (part of Multiattack), and Pounce is engaged (target makes save, etc). If everything works out, Deinonychus can then Bite the target as a bonus action, thanks to Pounce. It can then move 20ft to another target and do another Claw attack (final attack of Multiattack), engaging Pounce again, possibly knocking the target prone. However, Deinonychus has no more bonus actions to spend in order to make the Bite attack triggered by Pounce.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but I'm only seeing one bonus action used in the example. The last bite is part of the multiattack action, no?

Comment: @Someone_Evil It was a bit confusing, because Bite is both bonus action and part of multiattack. I put it as the first attack (although not the optimal strategy), hopefully making it clearer

Comment: I am confused. This seems to be exactly the same thing OP suggested. But OP is using the bite multiattack on the first target and the bite bonus action on the second. So, what he seems to be asking is just whether he can knock two enemies.

Comment: @HellSaint You're right, I misread OP's example. The answer still stands, and I've updated accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, you can do it.

If I am reading your question right, the order of events you are proposing is:

- Move 20 ft.
- Make a claw attack.
- Trigger Pounce.
- Target fails the saving throw and is knocked prone.
- You use the Bite as a bonus action.
- Move other 20 ft.
- Make a claw attack.
- Trigger Pounce.
- Does not matter whether target fails the saving throw or not.
- Use the Bite attack as the final part of the multiattack.

So, we need to answer four questions here:

1. Can the beast use its attacks in whatever order it wants?

Yes. Compare it to an Ancient Red Dragon Multiattack:

> ***Multiattack.*** The dragon can use its Frightful Presence. It then makes three attacks: one with its bite and two with its claws.

In this case, the order is specified. First, it needs to do X, then Y. In the beast case, it just states how many attacks can be done.

> ***Multiattack.*** The deinonychus makes three attacks: one with its bite and two with its claws.

2. Can the multiattack be interrupted by movement, and then continued?

Yes. Lacking a more specific rule, we use the general combat rules described in the PHB for moving between attacks, p. 190:

> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks. For example, a fighter who can make two attacks with the Extra Attack feature and who has a speed of 25 feet could move 10 feet, make an attack, move 15 feet, and then attack again.

Finally,
3. Can Pounce be triggered more than once per turn?

Yes. Pounce states

> Pounce. If the deinonychus moves at least 20 feet straight toward a creature and then hits it with a claw attack on the same turn, that target must succeed on a DC 12 Strength saving throw or be knocked prone. If the target is prone, the deinonychus can make one bite attack against it as a bonus action.

Nowhere it restricts the number of times it can be triggered in a turn or round - as long as the deinonychus has movement and attacks, it can keep triggering the feature.

Another question suggested by Medix2, which is also relevant.

4. Can you take a bonus action in the midst of the multi-attack?

And the answer is yes, you can. The general answer is given in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90779/43856), but essentially

> You choose when to take a bonus action during your turn, unless the bonus action's timing is specified

in this case, the timing is specified, and you can use the bonus action exactly at that timing (after knocking the enemy prone with pounce).

So, to conclude, **yes, the deinonychus can trigger pounce twice, and bite twice** (once by multiattack, once by using its bonus action).

Comment: @Medix2 Nice one, although even if we couldn't, we still would be able to use the Bite as the last attack (after the multiattack has already ended).

Comment: Oh right, I missed that that was an option, ah well