# Can a Banderhobb make 2 attacks and teleport?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, teleportation

The VGM's Banderhobb can grapple and restrain enemies with his attacks. The Tongue attack allows him to do a Bite attack as a bonus action.

> **Bite**. Melee Weapon Attack: +8 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target.
>   Hit: 22 (5d6 + 5) piercing damage.
>
> **Tongue**. Melee Weapon Attack: +8 to hit, reach 15 ft., one creature. Hit: 10 (3d6) necrotic damage, and the target must make
>   a DC 15 Strength saving throw. On a failed save, the target is
>   pulled to a space within 5 feet of the banderhobb, which can
>   use a bonus action to make a bite attack against the target.

He can also use his Shadow Step to teleport, and make an attack as part of the teleport, before or after teleporting.

> **Shadow Step**. The banderhobb magically teleports up to 30
>   feet to an unoccupied space of dim light or darkness that
>   it can see. Before or after teleporting, it can make a bite or
>   tongue attack

**Can the Banderhobb use Shadow Step to: Tongue an enemy, Bite him as a bonus action, and then teleport?**

Comment: Heavily related: [Can you break up your Attack action for a bonus action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72888/can-you-break-up-your-attack-action-for-a-bonus-action)

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, the Banderhobb can perform the described sequence of actions.

1. The Banderhobb uses its Action to Shadow Step
2. Before teleporting, it can use its Tongue attack on a target within reach as a part of Shadow Step
3. If the target fails the saving throw from the Tongue attack, the Banderhobb can also use its Bite attack agains the target as a bonus action
4. Regardless of how the Tongue and Bite attacks were resolved, it can then complete its Shadow Step and teleport away