# Do you have to shoot every shot in a Reload firearm before reloading?

Tags: dnd-5e, firearms, ammunition

In the DMG (p. 267), there are a number of [firearms](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#Firearms), some of which have the Reload [property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#Properties):

> ***Reload.*** A limited number of shots can be made with a weapon that has the reload property. A character must then reload it using an action or a bonus action (the character’s choice).

Since it says, "a character must **then** reload," does this mean that you have to expend each of the limited number of shots before you can reload? Or, can you reload after only using some of the limited number of shots?

Comment: I can see the follow-up question: "Do you **have to** reload after shooting every shot?" - no because battlefield pickup is fun and intuitive.

Answer (score 8):

### The rule is not preventing earlier reloads

Just because the user must reload the weapon when it runs out of ammo does not mean they cannot do so earlier. If someone tells you 'you must check in to your flight half an hour before the gate closes', nothing stops you from checking in earlier.

In fact, if you want to be very literal in reading, you could ask whether the character is *forced to use their action or bonus action* to reload -- *i.e.* they have no option not to reload, because the text says they *must* reload. I think this is clearly also not intended, but just imprecise writing.

It probably is best to read "**must then**" together. If you run out of ammo and want to continue using the weapon, you 'must then' reload. You are not required to reload, nor can you only *then* reload. But at that point in time ("then"), you cannot continue firing without reloading.

Answer (score 7):

### RAW, it could be read that way, RAI - no

The way I read, and apply it in game, is "A character must then reload it...[in order to be able to continue firing]". Pointing out that if your firearm is out of shots you must reload it to fire more. However, it *could* be read as "a character must **then** [and only then] reload".

In game, however, I can't imagine anyone running it this way. Though my real-life knowledge of firearms is limited I don't believe that is how things work. At most, in the case of dropping a half empty clip to insert a full one, you'll lose the remaining unfired bullets.

Talk to your DM, see how they want to run it.

Comment: The magazine doesn’t care if it still has bullets in it, you can drop it and reload a new one. For a revolver your are of course free to drop the cylinder and dump what’s in it - and it obviously doesn’t care if they are spent or unspent cases.

Comment: The exception being the round you have in the chamber, which would not be removed when the magazine was changed?

Comment: @KirtnoQA4mewhilemodsstrike Yeah, for a semiautomatic, magazine fed pistol or rifle, you would have to rack the slide/bolt to eject the chambered round.

Comment: @ThomasMarkovisonStrike So it seems like [in the question that prompted this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/207229/23547), with a 5 round magazine and two attacks per Attack action, one would fire twice the first round, fire twice the second round and then bonus action reload, and begin the third round with a round in the chamber and five in the magazine?

Comment: @KirtnoQA4mewhilemodsstrike No reason to even do that: take the bonus action to reload between the attacks of turn 3.

Comment: Some weapons could take longer to reload in case the previous cartridge is not fully used, examples include gatling-type guns where the chain link needs to be disengaged or the M1 Garand that ejects the clip when it's expended. As a rule of thumb though ejecting the cartridge is a failsafe for firearms, resuming combat within 6 seconds (1 round) is a design criterion.